# How to create a List<long> from a long variable?

Tags: c#, collections

how can i convert a long variable into the list?
Code:

```
long taskId = long.Parse(LocalWorkListVM.ActiveTask.TaskId, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I need to convert it into a `List<long>` because one of our method expect a list to pass.

Comment: What do you mean `long` to `List`? A `List` is a collection, a `long` is a single variable.

Comment: What means _"convert into"_, do you mean _add to_?

Comment: Yes, long is a single variable. I need to convert it into a list<long> because one of our method expect a list to pass

Comment: @Sandeep Please edit your question title to make your requirement clear. As it stands, it makes no sense without reading your comment.

Answer (score 3):

So you need a `List<long>` but you only have a single variable. That's easy, you can use the [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax:

```
List<long> longs = new List<long>{ taskId };
```

or more verbose with `List.Add`:

```
List<long> longs = new List<long>();
longs.Add( taskId );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
List<long> somelist = new List<long>{long.Parse(LocalWorkListVM.ActiveTask.TaskId, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)};
```

This will create a new `List` and initialise it with the parsed value.

Answer (score 0):

Does it really need to be a `List`? If there is a way to modify that method to accept an `IEnumerable` things would get much easier and cleaner (or if `IEnumerable` is not enough, maybe consider `IList`).

So considering this, you have a bunch of options.

You can use the `Enumerable` class' static method `Repeat`:

```
Enumerable.Repeat(taskId, 1);
```

You can write your own extension method:

```
static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this T item)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
// and use it as:
taskId.ToEnumerable()
```

Of course this extension method can be modified to return a `List` or `IList` or whatever your exact needs are.

Also, you might create a new overload of the function, which expects a single `long` instead of the `List`, somewhere along the lines of this:

```
public void MyMethod(List<long> list)
{
    // Do something
}

public void MyMethod(long item)
{
    MyMethod(new List<long>{ item });
}
```

And finally, there is a nice keyword called `params`:

```
public void MyMethod(params long[] items)
{
    // call to the previously mentioned extension method
    MyMethod(items.ToEnumerable());
}

public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<long> items)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

This solution has the advantage to work with a single `long` parameter, comma separated `long` parameters or with an `IEnumerable<long>`.